# Angular Get Spring Roles from JWT

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot, jwt, claims

I have two roles in my REST back-end (built with Spring):

**ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN**

When I log in, the REST API returns a valid token. Then I set it in the local storage like this:

```
localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({username: username, token: token}));
```

And when I need it I get it like this:

```
localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
```

So far so good. When I get my token how do I get the payload and the claims in it?

I want to show admin panel if you are an admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jwtHelper.decodeToken($scope.jwt)
```

See https://github.com/auth0/angular-jwt and https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt

an example https://github.com/auth0-blog/angularjs-jwt-authentication-tutorial/blob/8841ad5d7cb034506d2e3e6840db6202e6969b7a/frontend/home/home.js#L16

Comment: 10x, I have two concerns about the library:
1) this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(token) how is this going to decode my token if I dont provide the secret?
2) If I provide the secret somehow isn't that a vulnerability?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31953325/how-is-angular-jwt-decoding-my-jwt-without-a-secret check this

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed! :)

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to identify user role based on the token, Better add a new flag like IS_ROLE_USER, IS_ROLE_ADMIN and based on that flag check the current user role. Or else use spring boot security. Might it will help you.

Comment: I am using Spring Security. However, I don't know how to hide a div containing the Admin options.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers covered the spring part of your question, so I'm going to focus my answer on the angular part.

You can use a directive to show/hide the admin panel like so:

```
<admin-component *ngIf="user.isAdmin"></admin-component>
```